# C# Cancel Task with started List<>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, multitasking, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I started task with lists and await Task.WhenAll

```
private async void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        await DownloadMultipleFilesAsync(old_json);
        Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
    }
```

and that's my code that starting task with list.

```
private async Task DownloadMultipleFilesAsync(List<media> doclist)
    {
        var token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
        await Task.WhenAll(doclist.Select(doc => DownloadFileAsync(doc)));
        btn_download.Enabled = true;
    }
```

and my download method

```
private async Task DownloadFileAsync(media media)
{
    .
    .
    .
    Console.WriteLine(media.no + media_ext + " started.");
    webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(media.url), @downloadToDirectory);
    Console.WriteLine(media.no + media_ext + " finished.");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The output window like this:

```
1.jpg started.
2.jpg started.
3.jpg started.
4.jpg started.
5.jpg started.
6.jpg started.
7.jpg started.
8.jpg started.
9.jpg started.
10.jpg started.
11.jpg started.
12.jpg started.
13.jpg started.
14.jpg started.
15.jpg started.
16.jpg started.
17.jpg started.
18.jpg started.
19.jpg started.
1.jpg finished.
4.jpg finished.
2.jpg finished.
6.jpg finished.
8.jpg finished.
10.jpg finished.
3.jpg finished.
5.jpg finished.
12.jpg finished.
14.jpg finished.
7.jpg finished.
16.jpg finished.
18.jpg finished.
9.jpg finished.
11.jpg finished.
13.jpg finished.
15.jpg finished.
17.jpg finished.
19.jpg finished.
Download completed.
```

I want to click btn_cancel and cancel starting task and wait finish started task.

```
private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
    cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: Use `Task.WaitAll(doclist.Select(doc => DownloadFileAsync(doc)).ToArray(), token)`

Comment: @MatiasCicero I can't use like that http://prntscr.com/c9iiql

Comment: @SonerB You didn't call `ToArray()` after the `Select` ...

Comment: @MatiasCicero now I try. Downloading start and freezing program while it finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the cancellation token down the call chain then use it where possible, you also need to register a cancel call back to call [`WebClient.CancelAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx) to cancel the download.

```
private async void btn_download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .
    .
    .
    var token = cancelTokenSource.Token;
    try
    {
        await DownloadMultipleFilesAsync(old_json, token);
        Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        //If something other than our token caused the cancel bubble up the exception.
        if(ex.CancellationToken != token)
            throw;
    }
}


private async Task DownloadMultipleFilesAsync(List<media> doclist, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(doclist.Select(doc => DownloadFileAsync(doc, token));
    btn_download.Enabled = true;
}


private async Task DownloadFileAsync(media media, CancellationToken token)
{
    .
    .
    .
    Console.WriteLine(media.no + media_ext + " started.");
    webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    try
    {
        using(token.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync()))
        {
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(media.url), @downloadToDirectory);
        }
    }            
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        //Raise a OperationCanceledException if the request was canceled, otherwise bubble up the exception.
        if(ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
            throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
        else
            throw;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(media.no + media_ext + " finished.");
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried and working. But output window is full like this : http://prntscr.com/c9j0pg

Comment: You likely don't have ["Just My Code"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) turned on or you did somthing wrong in the `btn_download_Click` catch block to cause the exceptions to get through.

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` doesn't take a CancelationToken, which is weird.  Instead, it has a method [CancelAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx) you can call to cancel pending calls.

Seems like you'd have to keep a reference your webClient around, and call that method on clicking the cancel button.

Comment: You don't need to keep it around, just use a [`CancellationToken.Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) and call the function from inside the delegate, just pass the token in to the function down the chain.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, definitely, nice.  Haven't used that one before.  That would definitely abstract away the implementation details.

Comment: I am so sorry. I am learning C# and I don't know how I insert CancellationToken.Register my methods. Can you explain me or some example?

Comment: @SonerB look at the answer I posted, i show you how to change all the methods to do it.

Comment: @SonerB Scott gave you a full blown answer.  I would use his and mark it as the accepted answer